# How to amend Plugin code to output a CSS class

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm using a plugin to display the count of posts per category, but it does not output a CSS Class, so I can't style it.

Does anyone know how I amend the plugin's code to get it to output a CSS class?

The code is:

```
<?php 
    /*
    Plugin Name: Display Category Post Count
    Description: This plugin useful for displaying post count for any post/product category (simply use shortcode [get-post-count-wpcpc category="your category name" post_type="post/product/etc"])
    Author: Amit Maskare
    Version: 1.1
    Author URI: #
    */
class WPCPC{
    public function getPostCount($atts){
    global $wpdb;

    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'cat_name'  => $atts['category'],
        'post_type' => $atts['post_type'],
    ), $atts ) );

$get_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms terms INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships terms_rel ON terms.term_id = terms_rel.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts post ON post.ID = terms_rel.object_id WHERE terms.name = '".$cat_name."' AND post.post_status = 'publish' AND post.post_type = '".$post_type."'");

$rowcount = $wpdb->num_rows;
return $rowcount;
}
}

function get_post_count_wpcpc($atts){
$WPCPC = new WPCPC;
return $WPCPC->getPostCount($atts);
}

add_shortcode( 'get-post-count-wpcpc' , 'get_post_count_wpcpc' );
```

Comment: Why don't you just wrap it in your own class wherever you add the shortcode, e.g. `<span class="vote-count">[get_post_count_wpcpc]</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should not amend the plugin code. Also, the code you are using is not the ideal way. We must make use of [Wp_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

You can just change:

```
return $WPCPC->getPostCount($atts);

to 

return '<span class="postcount">'.$WPCPC->getPostCount($atts).'</span>';
```

Then you can use `.postcount` in your CSS.